# Transparent window in Xwindow parent

Tags: overlay, x11, transparent, xlib

I am trying to create an overlay window above another running application.
Let's say firefox. I implemented by using
Xcreatewindow

```
win = XCreateWindow( display, *firefoxwindow,
                   50, 300, 400, 400,
                   0,
                   visualinfo.depth,
                   InputOutput,
                   visualinfo.visual,
                   CWColormap|CWEventMask|CWBackPixmap|CWBorderPixel,
                   &attr
                   ) ;
```

I searched *firefoxwindow by using XQueryTree()

and then followed this code
https://gist.github.com/903479

The result is the transparent window when I use the XRoot as parent.
But, when I try to use firefoxwindow or other application window as parent, it became optique.

Answer (score 4):

In your case you need to composite window pixmap with background window manually. When you create window with root as parent transparency is handled by compositing window manager

Comment: Would you please guide me a little bit more, I'm quite new to this things.

Comment: with Composite extension ( http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/CompositeExt) you can delegate copmositing to external program, which coud, for example treat aplpha channel as a transparency. Very simple compositing manager source: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xcompmgr/

Comment: Thank you Andrey, one more question, do you think, is possible to run other application on the top of another full screen application?

Comment: usually full screen app uses just non-framed window (0,0,screen-width, screen-height) - no magic there. You should be able to restack window on top of it